# Symfony 403 error if I try to run the project

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose

I took a project with Symfony. I have never code in Symfony (I'm Laravel programmer) but it's app to the learn. So I try to run this with instruction via

```
docker-compose up -d
```

It's standard but all the time I have a 403 error - Forbidden. Docker-compose looks like this

```
version: "3.5"
# https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/

services:
  ak_invoice_php:
    container_name: ak_invoice_php
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/build/php/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8011:80"
    depends_on:
      - ak_invoice_mysql
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/build/php/conf.d/timezone.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/timezone.ini
      - ./docker/build/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini
    networks:
      - ak_invoice

  ak_invoice_mysql:
    container_name: ak_invoice_mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
#    image: beercan1989/arm-mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci --sql_mode="ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
    restart: always  # always | unless-stopped | on-failure | no
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "33075:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/build/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ${MYSQL_DOCKER_CNF-./docker/build/mysql/docker.cnf}:/etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf
      - ${MYSQL_SYSTEM_DIR-./mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-root} # (!)
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE:-ak_invoice}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER:-ak_invoice}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-ak_invoice123}
    networks:
      - ak_invoice

networks:
  ak_invoice:
    name: ak_invoice
```

I tryed change permissions to the files and directiries for this project but all the time is this same. I tryed make my own docker-compose but problem is this same. I know that we have on github repository to run symfony on docker but it doesn't work.

Anyway, my top priority is to get the project that was sent to me up and running. Why am I getting a 403 error?

Comment: so is your problem symfony/php related or you got broken docker setup? because I suspect the latter. if `symfony serve` does the job w/o the container, you should edit your tags accordingly

Comment: check the symfony log in var/log and docker container logs : `docker logs ak_invoice_php
docker logs ak_invoice_mysql ` and Check the Symfony security settings, routing, and access controls in the security.yaml and routes.yaml files, and ensure they are set up as expected.